# EclipseでCのデバッグでNo symbol table is loadedエラー

Tags: c, eclipse

表題の件でお助けいただけますでしょうか？

Windows10でAll in one Eclipse 4.5　Mars 32bit fulledition をダウンロードして新規プロジェクト作成→新規CプロジェクトでHelloWorld ANSI Cプロジェクトを生成しました。

コンパイラはVisualC++を設定、すでにひな形があるのでコンパイルと実行は出来たのですが、デバッグの際にエラーが出ます。

以下がそのエラーメッセージです。

```
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
[New Thread 35376.0x950c]
Error: dll starting at 0xf00000 not found.
Error: dll starting at 0x753a0000 not found.
Error: dll starting at 0xf00000 not found.
Error: dll starting at 0xf00000 not found.
[New Thread 35376.0x95d8]
[New Thread 35376.0x95fc]
Quit (expect signal SIGINT when the program is resumed)
```

デバッグの際のエラーなのでデバッガーか何かの設定なのかと思い設定を色々触っては試行錯誤していますが改善しません。

エラーの意味と対応法をご存知の方おられましたらお助け願えませんでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VisualC++はよくわからないので的を外してるかもしれませんが

> `No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.`

これはgdbが出力するエラーですね。

ビルドしたバイナリにデバッグシンボルが含まれてない場合に表示されるものです。
コンパイラがgccであれば`-g`をつけてビルドし直すと良いのですが、そもそも Eclipse CDTは VisualC++ のデバッグ情報は読み込めないのだと思います。

素直にVisualC++を使うか、[Debuging tools for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ff551063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) を使うのが良いのではと思います。